# google_maps_flutter - How to draw polyline without calling setState?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

On my app, I'm collecting user's location and I'm drawing the user's itinerary using `google_maps_flutter` to draw the polyline.

Currently I am drawing the polyline by replacing it every 5 seconds like this:

```
if (this.mounted) {
  setState(() {
    _polylines[polylineId] = Polyline(
        visible: true,
        width: 7, 
        polylineId: polylineId,
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 115, 239),
        points: polylineCoordinates);
  });
}
```

Nothing particular as you can see but the frequent calls to setState are making the map unresponsive and are using a lot of ressources in the process.

I'm wondering if there is a way to draw a polyline dynamically without having to use setState ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check ChangeNotifier and notifyListeners.

Comment: Yes this is what I am using and I trigger the notifyListener every 5 seconds. I could increase the delay but then the itinerary won't appear as the user moves.